# relationship between $f_\pi:\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(N)$ and $\deg(f)$

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups, compact-manifolds

> Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between compact connected oriented
>   n-dimensional differentiable manifolds. Assume that the image of the
>   map on fundamental groups $f_\pi:\pi_1(M, m_0)\to \pi_1(N,f(m_0))$ has
>   finite index $D$. Prove that $\deg(f)$ is divisible by $D$.

I just have no idea how something about the fundamental groups can reveal information about the degree of a map! It may be far beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Do you know covering space theory, lifting lemmas, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Let $F = f_{\pi}(\pi_1(M))$. The classification of covering spaces tells us that there is a covering space $p: X \to N$ such that $p_{\pi}(\pi_1(X)) = F$. In particular, $f$ has a unique lifting $\tilde{f}$ such that $f = p\circ \tilde{f}$.  Note that for any finite sheeted covering, the degree of the map is exactly the number of sheets, so the degree of our map $p$ is exactly the index of $F$ in $\pi_1(N)$. Then since the degree is multiplicative, we have that

$$\text{deg}(f) =\left(\text{deg}(\tilde{f})\right) \left(\text{deg}(p)\right) $$

And by the above comment the result.

Comment: As Lee points out in the comments, this answer requires quite a bit of familiarity with covering spaces. The only fact it uses about degree is that it's multiplicative with respect to composition of maps.